# Dot product with a difference maximum angle

Tags: inner-products

In a program I'm making I use the dot product to get a value between 1 and 0 dependent on the angle between two vectors. The value is 0 if the vectors are parallel and 1 if they are perpendicular. What I am looking for now, is a way to have an extra variable which defines the angle at which this value should be maximal(1), instead of always using 90 degrees.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are converting from degrees to your new unitless [0,1] range, then it is `x = angle_in_degrees/maximal_angle`.

Comment: Hm I think I asked my question in a bad way. I meant for a modified dot product where my variable 'range' modifies the angle at which the formula is maximal. For example, when range is 1, it is the normal dot product with 0 degrees = 0 and 90 degrees = 1. If range is 0.5, 0 degrees is still 0, but 45 degrees is now 1.

Comment: In that case, use `x = angle_in_degrees/(90 * range)`.  For example, 45/(90*0.5) = 1.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm able to figure it out now. Thanks